# string Regex that finds digits

Tags: c#

I`m having problems with Regex.
I have a line
Collapse | Copy Code

> Contract Nr.123456,reg.Nr.654321-118

I want to use a regex that Finds only the string 123456, but doesn't find the second 6 digit- 3 digit string(654321-118)

This is what i came up with, but don't really know what to do next
Collapse | Copy Code

```
string regex4 = @"\d{4,6}[^-]";
```

Any Ideas?
Thank you.

---the comma isn't specific, I think I need to build the regex so It didn't find strings that end with the "-" sign

---This is payment details in the bank, field-recievers info. There are two possible sets of digits xxxxxx and xxxxxx-xxx, I need to find only the first one.

Comment: Your regex is correct...

Comment: If there are always two such groups, and you only want to find the first group, then just don't search for the second one afterwards... `Regex.Match()` will find the **first** occurence of the pattern in the string, you then (don't) use `Match.NextMatch()` to get the next occurence.

Comment: Otherwise, you could use a negative lookahead: `\d{4,6}(?!-)`. (Your original regex would fail if the 4-6 digits were at the end of a string, since it requires one character that's not `-` to follow.)

Answer (score 0):

A bit crude but if it's pure numbers only you are concerned about and only the first occurance of it then you can do something simple like,

```
const string stuff = "Contract Nr.123456,reg.Nr.654321-118";

var regex = new Regex(@"\d+");

Console.WriteLine(regex.Match(stuff).Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could do this. For example you could match both \d+ and \d+-\d+ and THEN select only \d+ ones. Although, I like look-ahead and look-behind approach (note: I introduced line breaks and comments for readability, they should be remover)

```
(?<!\d+-\d*) -- there is NO number in front
\d+          -- I AM THE number
(?!\d*-\d+)  -- there is NO number behind
```

so, your regex looks like:

```
const string stuff = "Contract Nr.123456,reg.Nr.654321-118";
var rx = new Regex(@"(?<!\d+-\d*)\d+(?!\d*-\d+)");
Console.WriteLine(rx.Match(stuff).Value);
// result: 123456
```

or, if you want all non-hyphenated numbers in string:

```
const string stuff = "Contract Nr.123456,reg.Nr.654321-118 and 435345";
var rx = new Regex(@"(?<!\d+-\d*)\d+(?!\d*-\d+)");
var m = rx.Match(stuff);
while (m.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
    m = m.NextMatch();
}
// result: 123456 and 435345
```

**NOTE**: And next time try to be more specific because, to be honest, answer to the question you asked is "regular expression which matches '123456' is... '123456'".

**NOTE**: I tested it with LinqPad.